# Setup Neovim 0.5 lspconfig and F#

Tags: f#, neovim, nvim-lspconfig

I am trying to setup f# language server with neovim lsp. I have this in init.lua

```
nvim_lsp.fsautocomplete.setup{
  capabilities = capabilities,
  on_attach = on_attach,
  cmd = {'dotnet', '/Users/aritra/fsautocomplete.netcore/fsautocomplete.dll', '--background-service-enabled'},
  root_dir = nvim_lsp.util.root_pattern('*.sln', '.git', '*.fsproj')
}
```

I can see that lsp is attached to the client but no lsp feature is working. It gives an error like this `RPC[Error] code_name = Internal Error, message = "Cahced typecheck results not yet available"`

Also, `fsautocomplete` is now available from `dotnet` toolchain. How do I set this up properly so that lsp features work properly with any F# project or files?

Answer (score 0):

Install `fsautocomplete` globally using `dotnet tool install fsautocomplete --global`.

As of `fsautocomplete` version 0.46.2, one can use the setup below

```lua
local nvim_lsp = require("lspconfig")

nvim_lsp.fsautocomplete.setup{
  capabilities = capabilities,
  on_attach = on_attach,
  cmd = {'<path to dotnet-fsautocomplete>', '--background-service-enabled'},
}
```

Hover, lsp diagnostics, code formatting and code actions are working as expected.